# Bootstrap DateTime multi dates picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-multidatespicker

I have a bootstrap **datetime** picker component on my page. Is it possible to enable multidate selection?

thank you

Comment: It seems u can't do that. If u don't need time, may be u can try: `bootstrap-datepicker` : http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=true&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Answer (score 1):

The date pickers i have seen so far for bootstrap do not have multiple datepickers but its easy to use jquery ui date picker and give it a bootstrap feel using jquery ui bootstrap theme http://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/components.html#calendar .

Just add multi date picker from here http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js

and define the id `<input id="my_multi_date_picker" type="text"/>` and then add this jquery code

`$('#my_multi_date_picker').multiDatesPicker();`

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qyjm1hup/1/

With bootstrap theme http://jsfiddle.net/ejt6jroo/1/

Comment: I am getting an error Conversion from "string" format not allowed on jQuery.multiDatesPicker

Comment: Kindly try using jquery migrate https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/ in your page.

Comment: Migrate has functions that may be deprecated in v 2.0.3.

Comment: multi datepicker work with bootstrap 2. anyone has a solution for bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 1):

i don't use bootstrap, but i solve this issue by modifying the jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js file. Just add another case for boolean in the `switch(from_format)`(line 234) of `dateConvert` method, should look like this

```
switch(from_format) {
                case 'object': break;
                case 'string': date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, date); break;
                case 'boolean': date = ""; break;
                case 'number': date = new Date(date); break;
                default: $.error('Conversion from "'+ from_format +'" format not allowed on jQuery.multiDatesPicker');
            }
```

sorry for my bad english :)